# Add required to LabelFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having the following code:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

And I'm looking for a way to add the html attribute `required` to it, so a user can't submit without having the field filld. But now sure how to do? I know the easies way is to add  `required` But don't know how, i tryed with `@html "reguired"` Without any luck.

EDIT:
Answere = required = ""

Comment: Thank you! That was what i needed!

Comment: @AgentFire in this case user can crate post request manually and save entity without title. It is wrong from the security-point.

Comment: Add the required attribute to your model property

Answer (score 2):

You can add [RequiredAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to your model property:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
public string Title { get;set; }
```

And add ValidationMessageFor to your cshtml:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Model)
```

Then add model validation to controller method [via](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model). It's the standard pipeline for asp.net mvc.

You also can implement [your own HtmlHepler](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-how-to-show-asterisk-after-required-field-label) to add required attribute to your html code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need this for client validation

```
"~/Scripts/jquery.js"
, "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"
,"~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
```

whereas for only server side on Controller or necessary even if some disables javascript

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
```

As above using annotation

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]
public string Title { get;set; }
```

Using Fluent API

```
    public class ClassNameConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ClassName>
    {
        public ClassNameConfiguration()
        {
            Property(x => x.Title).IsRequired();
        }
    }
```